# VBA Loop to Highlight Inconsistencies

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a spreadsheet with two columns (A and B). I would like to (FOR) loop through column B until two or more of the cell values match. For the cells that match in column B, I would like to loop through their corresponding values in column A. If their corresponding values are not identical, I want all of the rows involved to be highlighted.

I know it's not right/complete, but below is the basic structure I would like to follow. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub MySUb()
  Dim iRow As Integer

  For iRow = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Trim(range("A" & iRow)) <> "" And Trim(range("B" & iRow)) = Trim(range("B" & iRow)) Then
      range("A" & iRow, "B" & iRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first sort based on Column B, then modify your code to:

```
Sub MySUb()
  Dim iRow As Integer

  For iRow = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Trim(Range("A" & iRow).Text) <> "" And _
    Trim(Range("B" & iRow).Text) = Trim(Range("B" & iRow + 1).Text) And _
    Trim(Range("A" & iRow).Text) <> Trim(Range("A" & iRow + 1).Text) Then
      Range("A" & iRow, "B" & iRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
      Range("A" & iRow + 1, "B" & iRow + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

[image: Sample table]

**EDIT:**
Here is a better solution which can handle the case where in column B there >2 matching cells, but the corresponding cells in A do not match (i.e. at least one of them is different). In this case **all** of those cells are marked.

```
 Sub MySUb()
  Dim iRow As Integer
  Dim jRow As Integer
  Dim kRow As Integer

  For iRow = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'If Trim(Range("A" & iRow).Text) <> "" Then
    For jRow = iRow To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Finds the last non-matching item in B
     If Trim(Range("B" & jRow).Text) <> Trim(Range("B" & iRow).Text) Then
       Exit For
     End If
    Next jRow
    For kRow = iRow To jRow - 1
     If Trim(Range("A" & iRow).Text) <> Trim(Range("A" & kRow).Text) Then
      Range("A" & iRow, "B" & kRow).Interior.ColorIndex = jRow + 1 'Or can be 6
     End If
    Next kRow
  Next iRow
End Sub
```

[image: Sample table]

Comment: @Chicken_Hawk: What error do you get? It works for me on my sample data.

Comment: @Chicken_Hawk: I think the problem is that your cell values are not numbers. Try my updated code above that uses .text

Comment: Pretty close but doesn't account for >2 match in Col B with two or more matches in Col A.

Comment: ^Precisely. And the values in column B are not always sequential.

Comment: @Chicken_Hawk: Updated the solution. What do you mean by sequential? My assumption is that you first sort the rows based on column B.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, using a dictionary to track the instances of an item in Column B and then testing the Column A values for each unique instance of Column B values. If one fails to match then all instances are marked.

```
Sub DuplicateChecker()
    Dim rngColumnB As Range
        Set rngColumnB = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngDupe As Range
    Dim rngDuplicateB As Range
    Dim dctValuesChecked As Dictionary 
        'requires enabled reference library for 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
        Set dctValuesChecked = New Dictionary
    Dim strColumnAValue As String

    For Each rngCell In rngColumnB
        strColumnAValue = rngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        If Not dctValuesChecked.Exists(Trim(rngCell.Value)) Then
            Call dctValuesChecked.Add(rngCell.Value, rngCell.Row)
        Else
            Set rngDuplicateB = FindItemsInRange(rngCell.Value, rngColumnB)
            rngDuplicateB.EntireRow.Select
            For Each rngDupe In rngDuplicateB
                If Not rngDupe.Offset(0, -1).Value = strColumnAValue Then
                    rngDuplicateB.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    rngDuplicateB.Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            Next rngDupe
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Sub

Function FindItemsInRange(varItemToFind As Variant, _
                            rngSearchIn As Range, _
                            Optional LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, _
                            Optional LookAt As XlLookAt = xlPart, _
                            Optional blnMatchCase As Boolean = False) As Range

'adapted from a function by Aaron Blood found on the Ozgrid forums:
'http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27240

    With rngSearchIn
        Dim rngFoundItems As Range
            Set rngFoundItems = .Find(What:=varItemToFind, _
                                            LookIn:=LookIn, _
                                            LookAt:=LookAt, _
                                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                            MatchCase:=blnMatchCase, _
                                            SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rngFoundItems Is Nothing Then
            Set FindItemsInRange = rngFoundItems
            Dim strAddressOfFirstFoundItem As String
                strAddressOfFirstFoundItem = rngFoundItems.Address
            Do
                Set FindItemsInRange = Union(FindItemsInRange, rngFoundItems)
                Set rngFoundItems = .FindNext(rngFoundItems)
            Loop While Not rngFoundItems Is Nothing And _
                            rngFoundItems.Address <> strAddressOfFirstFoundItem
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Karl! This appears to work, but it gives me a Run time error 457. "This key is already associated with an element of this collection"

Comment: Have been looking at this on the assumption that when you hit the Debug button it would highlight `Call dctValuesChecked.Add(rngCell.Value, rngCell.Row)`. I'm not sure how that could happen though since it only adds if the `rngCell.Value` key does not exist. Are you running this on multiple sheets or workbooks without ending the sub?  If so,  try adding `Set dctValuesChecked = Nothing` just after `Next rngCell`.